# Header Not 100% When Displayed In Mobile Devices

Tags: android, html, css

I have created a header that disappears when the user scrolls down. However the header floats to the left leaving what amounts to a 20px gap on the right hand side, when displayed on a mobile device. I do not know how to fix it and would be great full for any help that can be provided.

I have created 4 divs to hold this header in place. The first two is the header bar which is causing the issue. The issue can be solved if the position is set to fixed, the scrolling does not work

```
#HeaderBar {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../image-core/header.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute; z-index: 100;
}

#HeaderBar #HeaderBarContainer {
    width: 980px; 
    margin: 0px auto; 
    text-align: center; 
    height: 76px; 
}
```

The next div contains the logo which is positioned to the left

```
#HeaderBar #HeaderBarContainerLeft {
    width: 200px; 
    float: left; 
    text-align: left; 
}
```

The final div positions the navigation bar to the right of the logo

```
#HeaderBar #HeaderBarContainerRight {
    width: 690px; 
    float: right; 
    padding: 23px 0px 0px 0px; 
    text-align:right; 
    font-size: 16.5px;
    color: #FFF; 
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aLswsxbt/